# Why am I getting "Connection Refused" when using "host.docker.internal" to hit the host's localhost?

Tags: macos, docker, curl

I have the following...

```yml
version: "3.9"
services:
  proxy:
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    environment:
      - UI_URL=http://host.docker.internal:8000
      - API_URL=http://host.docker.internal:4200
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./proxy
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "443:443"
```

```
FROM nginx:alpine
WORKDIR /proxy
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.template
COPY host.crt .
COPY host.key .
COPY pre-boot.sh .
ENTRYPOINT [ "/proxy/pre-boot.sh" ]
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
EXPOSE 443
```

But when I run an application I can't access it on the proxy container...

1. Deploy container
2. Go to terminal on host machine
3. Use terminal to confirm the app can be accessed locally `curl http://localhost:8000` on the host. It displays the HTML expected
4. Open terminal in proxy container
5. Run `curl http://host.docker.internal:8000` but I get `curl: (7) Failed to connect to host.docker.internal port 8000 after 2 ms: Connection refused`

This was working so not sure what might have changed. Does anyone know why `localhost` would work but `host.docker.internal` on the container would fail? I am on MacOs

Comment: You define ports as 443 then host insecure HTTP traffic on ports 8000 and 4200.  It's likely due to the fact your NOT using a TLS certificate.

Comment: "This was working"—absolutely not. You cannot reach the host's `localhost` listeners from a Docker container. That would be a tremendous security problem. With macOS, it's doubly impossible. // Why do you want a setup like that? It's redundant.

Comment: @DanielB I know it's been a while, but can you elaborate here? The Docker Desktop docs say you *can* do this. Why is it doubly impossible on macOS? Why is it a redundant setup? What's a non redundant setup?

Comment: @oorst Not sure where you think the docs say this is possible. I didn't find anything like that. // If you want extensive information, I recommend you ask your own question. Comments aren't the place to discuss this.

Comment: @DanielB Fair enough. This is where I think the docs say this is possible [https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host)

Comment: @oorst This page does not say you can connect to your host’s `localhost`. Because that’s what’s impossible. On macOS (and Windows), Docker is running in a VM, making it even more impossible.

Comment: But that section in the docs shows setting up a Python webserver and connecting to it from the container. I think those python webservers listen at `0.0.0.0`. Is that the difference?

Comment: @oorst Yes, that is exactly the difference.